# url encoding qr barcode

Tags: barcode, qr-code, urlencode

i'm creating a qr barcode testing a website

http://test.com/test/ctrl/emain.asp?ctrlnumber=BAAAMYINQ

when creating a qr barcode the website must be url encoded so I change it to

http://test.com/test/ctrl/emain.asp%3Fctrlnumber%3DBAAAMYINQ

when I do this the website no longers works?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please better describe your problem. "no longer works" isn't precise enough. Does it crash? Does it produce the wrong result? Describe exactly what you expect to happen and what happens instead. And what does "a qr barcode testing a website" mean? Who is testing whom? What exactly are you creating? And if possible, show source code.

Comment: See also: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thanks for your comment. when I url encode the website the link fails and does not bring to the proper site. I get a 404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. I'm creating a qr barcode that will link directly to website so the client can view there material. Hop this helps.

Comment: I'll suggest you to use an url rewriter (or better, set up your own), so you'll be able to update your qrcode encoded link even if their destination isn't at the same url or has been replaced/removed, and you won't have to worry about the final url characters.